# Laravel Loading Animation with DOMPDF

Tags: ajax, laravel, animation, dompdf

I am using DOMPDF to generate a PDF and I want to display a loading animation/icon as long as the PDF is generated.

My Controller looks like:

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('backend.menubuilder.templates.tempone', compact('user'));
    return $pdf->download('wochenkarte.pdf');
```

And my JS in the view is:

```
var timeout;
function loaded() {
  $('#loading').html('The Ajax Call Data');
}

$('#start_call').click(startLoad);

function startLoad() {
  /*This is the loading gif, It will popup as soon as startLoad is called*/
  $('#loading').html('<img src="http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/shared_images/ajax-loader.gif"/>');

  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(loaded, 1500);
}
```

What I get with the code above is an animation for a couple of seconds when I hit the button, but not as long as the pdf is generated. How can I animate the gif as long as DOMPDF is generating the pdf?

Thanks

Comment: The JS is doing exactly as you asked it to, modify the `#loading` element then clear it after 1.5 seconds. I don't see anywhere in your JS view where you actually call the action that generates the PDF. When is this JS view loaded in relation to the PDF generating action?

Answer (score 1):

use the callback in `$.ajax().always()` in the ajax call to remove the animation.

more [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)